# Cannot access when security=users

Tags: opensuse, samba4

I cant access to files as annonymous or Linux account while `security = users` but when  `security = share` everything works fine. 
My config:

```
# smb.conf is the main Samba configuration file. You find a full commented
# version at /usr/share/doc/packages/samba/examples/smb.conf.SUSE if the
# samba-doc package is installed.
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    printcap cache time = 750
    cups options = raw
    map to guest = Bad User
    include = /etc/samba/dhcp.conf
    logon path = \\%L\profiles\.msprofile
    logon home = \\%L\%U\.9xprofile
    logon drive = P:
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    security = share
    netbios name = DamianR
    host allow = 192.168.
    encrypt passwords = yes 
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
    hide dot files = Yes
    create mask = 640
    directory mask = 640
    valid users = damian
[publiczny]
        comment = publiczny 
        inherit acls = Yes
        path = /home/damian/Publiczny
    available = yes
        browseable = yes
        writable = no
    read only = yes
        guest ok = yes 
    hide dot files = Yes
```

By the way I would like to ask if config is secure? I mean if password is encrypted while logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. line `security = users` should be before `map to guest = Bad User`